# silverlight c# textwrapping

Tags: silverlight

I am creating a text block object in c#, so I don't have any XAML for it. How can I enable textwrapping on this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock(/*params*/)

textBlock.TextWrap = TextWrapping.Wrap;
```

or

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock(/*params*/) { TextWrap = TextWrapping.Wrap};
```

Comment: +1 but drop the `/*params*/` stuff `TextBlock` only has a default constructor